# Calculate with 2 functions

Tags: c, function, int

I am a Beginner in Functions.I wanna integrate that Functions in my main program. The program should scan a int number and then square it(sum=b*b). Then the program should output the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void funktion(int);
void out(int);
int main(int)
{
int sum,b,v,w,z;
{
    funktion();
    calculator();
    out();
    printf("%i",sum);
}
return 0;
}

void funktion(int v)
{
printf("Enter any number that is to be squared!");
}
void calculator(int w) //calculate b*b
{
scanf("%i",&b);
sum=b*b;
}
void out(int z)
{
printf("Sum:");
}
```

Please give me some tips. ;)
Thx & Best regards!

Comment: What is the specific issue that you are facing?

Comment: Any decent beginners book or tutorial will have good chapters about this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this kind of solution: i just made little changes. you may need to do some initializing things if u gonna use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void funktion(int);
void out(int);
int main()
{
int sum,b;
{
    printf("Enter any number that is to be squared!");  
    scanf("%i",&b);

    sum = funktion(b);
    out(sum);
}
return 0;
}

int funktion(int b)
{
    return b*b;
}
void out(int sum)
{
    printf("Sum:%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: Prototype is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
void funktion(int)
{
printf("Enter any number that is to be squared!");
}
void out(int)
{
printf("Sum:");
}
```

to call these functions you are passing some value so you receive them with parameters.

```
void funktion(int a)
{
printf("Enter any number that is to be squared!");
}
void out(int b)
{
printf("Sum:");
}
```

You can make use of the passed value in functions using these variables, a nd b in corresponding functions.
If you dont want to access those passed values in the called functins then you dont need to pass the value. So change the functions to receive nothing, it can be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void funktion();
void out();
int main()
{
int sum,b;
{
    funktion();
    scanf("%i",&b);
    sum=b*b;
    out();
    printf("%i",sum);
}
return 0;
}

void funktion()
{
printf("Enter any number that is to be squared!");
}
void out()
{
printf("Sum:");
}
```

make the call to function without passing arguments. you can even specify `void` as type to indicate that function doesn't take any parameters.
To calculate in other function and return the value use `return` statement.

```
int calculator() //calculate b*b
{
scanf("%i",&b);
sum=b*b;
 return sum;
}
```

change the function call statement to,

```
sum=calculator();
```

Comment: thx. I´ve edited my Question.How can i calculate in a function and give the result to the out function?

Comment: @user3336852 i mentioned how to return value. But remember that its not good to make changes to question. and also read about functions in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
void funktion(int);
void out(int);
```

These two functions need not contain any arguments as you declared to be `int's`, because you are not performing any computation on `sum`, since they are just prints inside those functions.

So make them as,

```
void funktion(void);
void out(void);
```

and call those routines as,

```
funktion();
out();
```

Comment: In C, declaring a function with an empty argument list is *not* the same as making them take no arguments. Instead they now take an unknown number of arguments, and the compiler will infer the number and types of the arguments with the first call. In C, if you want to say a function has no arguments, you *must* make it `void`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes you are true. My mistake in hurry.

Comment: As for the scope, that's not true. How else would e.g. a block in a loop be able to access variables not declared in that block? Nested blocks nests the scope, but the scope in the block always includes the scope of the outer block.